# How to update only one column in excel dataset using SQL statement

Tags: sql, excel, automationanywhere

I have a table, in this I need to update company as BOFA in only one column.
I used this:

```
UPDATE [SHEET1&] SET COMPANY = "BOFA" where SNO = 101 AND NAME='NIKE';
```

but it is updating both the columns, but I want only one column to be updated where two columns match:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean *"but it is updating both ROWS... I want only one ROW to be updated"*. If so, you'll have to specify which row it is you want it to update. How would it know which one otherwise?

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541411/update-a-column-of-same-table-if-there-is-duplicate-records. It might help you.

Comment: @JNevill I need to update the second row COMPANY to BOFA from CTS and third row need to be in TCS only

Comment: What is the logic for that. How do you establish the order of these records? Is there a date or an `id` that increments or alphabetically by `COMPANY`? Or is the logic more simply like "Update a row that is both 101 and Company of CTS to BOFA"?

Comment: @JNevill, I need to update only one row where two row's data matches with same value. I have to apply this in my excel sheet which I have many columns and COMPANY column will be empty by default, So If SNO and NAME are having same values and need to update COMPANY to BOFA in either one record, the other one remains empty

Comment: SNO NAME COMPANY
100 MIKE Capone
101 NIKE 
101 NIKE

Comment: @Selvakumar Have you mis-quoted  *columns* where you meant *rows* in your question? Without seeing before, after, and expected results all in your question, it is difficult to formulate an answer. And did you resolve this in the end?